# Specify default attribute selection behavior in sails model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, sails.js

I am new to sails.

In MongoDB there is an option such that an attibute can be excluded by default.

For example

```
var Person = new Schema({ bio: { type: String, select: false },
                          other: {type:String, select:true }})
var P = db.model('Person', Person);
P.findOne(function (err, p) {
  console.log(p.bio) // undefined
  console.log(p.other) // it will get the data from database
});
```

How to set this option in sails.js?

Is that possible?

I have searched but didn't get any answer.